# PyJWT returning invalid token signatures

Tags: python, firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication, pyjwt

I'm using PyJWT==1.4.2 to generate tokens that I intend to use for Firebase authentication.

Unfortunately I'm not able to use any of the third-party Python Firebase libraries, and even if I could I had the same difficulty when I tried with FirebaseTokenGenerator.

Inside of my API, I have a function for generating a token for a username.

```
118     def generate_token(self, username):
119         payload = {
120             'something': 'Here',
121         }   
122         secret = "TESTSECRET"
123         token = jwt.encode(
124             payload,
125             secret,
126             algorithm='HS256')
127         return token
```

An example of a token I get from this function is:

> `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzb21ldGhpbmciOiJIZXJlIn0.fpIMSRJ3AAL30LIDwHJM9ZOumdRzS7yooiiUgMPms2Y`

Unfortunately, this is not a valid token. Online resource such as https://jwt.io/ are telling me that the signature portion is invalid.

Not sure if this is further helpful info, but when I try decoding the token I get the following:

```
b'{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}{"something"[83 chars]\x88'
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is indeed a valid token, if you go to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and paste that token **and then update the secret used to verify it** to be the same you used to generate the token then the tool will indicate that the signature is valid.

By default, [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) tries to validate the signature using the HS256 algorithm and the default secret of `secret`. You're indeed creating a JWT using the HS256 algorithm so the only thing you need to do to check if it's valid is to update the secret input box to use `TESTSECRET`.

Also, the signature component of JWT is raw binary data that may not display correctly if you try to decode it to text. For a bit more on how JWT's work you can check [Get Started with JSON Web Tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/).

Comment: *smashes head on keyboard* I didn't change my secret back from what I had before. That was indeed the problem.

Furthering the issue, I wasn't aware that decoding the JWT wouldn't necessarily display properly. When I tried to do so with 

**decoded = base64.b64decode(token)**

I got either an "incorrect padding" error or a cut-off version of my payload. That resource is extremely, helpful, thank you!

Comment: In software development it's always the small details that get us... welcome to the club. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
example_payload = {
    'public_id': user.public_id,
    'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow()+datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
}
```

For ENCODING use

```
token = jwt.encode(example_payload,app.config['SECRET_KEY'],algorithm="HS256")
```

For DECODING use

```
data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=["HS256"])
```

basically just adding the ALGORITHM and ALGORITHMS=[] parts... otherwise it gave me error (token invalid for operations after the log-in), but this fixed it.

In Python3 you don't need the ".decode('UTF-8')" after "jwt.encode()": it does it for you.

Also check you don't have both jwt and PyJWT packages:

```
pip3 list
```

if you have both jwt and PyJWT installed then do:

```
pip3 uninstall jwt
pip3 uninstall PyJWT
pip3 install PyJWT
```

re-run your app

Answer (score 2):

I guess with the latest version of PyJWT while decoding you need to use the algorithm.

I was facing the same issue. Solved it using the algorithm parameter. The PyJwt version I'm using is 2.0.1. Below is the sample code. Please try and let me know if it works.

```
payload = jwt.decode("YOUR_JWT_TOKEN","YOUR_SECRET_KEY", algorithms=["HS256"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try appending `.decode("utf-8")` to the decode function.

Answer (score 0):

in any case someone use it like me and create token with this methood

```
    from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=access_token)
```

you shold add in your app.py

```
app.config['algorithms'] = ["HS256"]
```

I'm using PyJWT  2.1.0